# Операции со списками в python

Tags: python, циклы, списки

Есть 2 списка lst и new_list. 
Почему выражение

`new_list[0] = (3*lst[0]+2*lst[0+1]+lst[0+2]-lst[0+4])/5` работает, а выражение

```
for i in range(lst[2], lst[-3]):
    new_list[i] = (4*lst[i]+3*lst[i-1]+2*lst[i-2]+lst[i-3])/10
```

не работает? Ошибка "IndentationError: expected an indented block"
И как сделать, чтобы программа брала элементы из списка lst, пересчитывала их и отправляла в список new_list?

Весь код

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd
import scipy
import numpy as np
file_location = "C:/Users/Blame/Desktop/graph.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_col = sheet.col_values(0)
second_col = sheet.col_values(1)
lst = [sheet.col_values(0)]
x = second_col
y = first_col
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,y,'ro',x,p(x),'r--')
plt.plot(second_col, first_col)
plt.title('60%')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('temperature')  
new_list = []
new_list[0] = (3*lst[0]+2*lst[0+1]+lst[0+2]-lst[0+4])/5
new_list[1] = (4*lst[1]+3*lst[1+1]+2*lst[1+2]+lst[1+3])/10
for i in range(len(lst)-4):
new_list[i] = (4*lst[i]+3*lst[i-1]+2*lst[i-2]+lst[i-3])/10
new_list.extend(i)
return new_list
new_list[-2] = (4*lst[-2]+3*lst[-2-1]+2*lst[-2-2]+lst[-2-4])/10
new_list[-1] = (3*lst[-1]+2*lst[-1-1]+lst[-1-2]-lst[-1-4])/5
print(new_list)
```

Входной массив `[[90.0, 72.0, 68.5, 65.0, 62.0, 60.0, 59.0, 58.0, 57.0, 56.0, 54.0, 53.0, 52.0, 51.0, 50.0, 49.0, 48.0, 47.5, 46.5, 46.0, 45.0, 44.5, 46.0, 45.0, 44.5, 44.0, 43.0, 42.5, 41.5, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 40.5, 40.5, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0]]`

UPD: Всё работает.

`lst=[90.0, 72.0, 68.5, 65.0, 62.0, 60.0, 59.0, 58.0]
print(lst)
new_list = []
new_list.append((3*lst[0]+2*lst[0+1]+lst[0+2]-lst[0+4])/5)
new_list.append((4*lst[1]+3*lst[1+1]+2*lst[1+2]+lst[1+3])/10)
for i in range(2, len(lst)-2):
   new_list.append((lst[i-2]+lst[i-1]+lst[i]+lst[i+1]+lst[i+2])/5)
new_list.append((4*lst[-2]+3*lst[-2-1]+2*lst[-2-2]+lst[-2-4])/10)
new_list.append((3*lst[-1]+2*lst[-1-1]+lst[-1-2]-lst[-1-4])/5)
print(new_list)`

Осталось только разбить мой собственный входной массив, который выдает xlrd здесь: `lst = [sheet.col_values(0)]`
Не работало, потому что это просто строка и весь массив из одного этого элемента состоит.

Comment: А как вы поняли что выражение в цикле не работает? Если возникает ошибка добавьте ее к вопросу, если алгоритм неправильный, приведите весь ваш код (как минимум не хватает `new_list` и `lst`) а также формулу по которой код делали. А так по вашему огрызку кода можно только угадывать что там не так

Comment: не понимаю как работает ваша формула: `(4*lst[i]+3*lst[i-1]+2*lst[i-2]+lst[i-3])/10`, при `i=2`, ведь `lst[i-3]` будет: `lst[-1]` - т.е. последний элемент списка (`58.0`)

Comment: @MaxU исправил на рабочую формулу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что для (например) списка `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

```
range(lst[2], lst[-3])
```

то же самое, что

```
range(3, 4)
```

или просто `[3]`
(Для вашего примера: `range(lst[2], lst[-3]) == range(68.5, 40)`, что приведет к `TypeError`)

Правильно написать

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
   new_list[i] = (4*lst[i]+3*lst[i-1]+2*lst[i-2]+lst[i-3])/10
```

---

Если я правильно понимаю, верный код будет таким:

```
new_list = []
new_list.append((3*lst[0]+2*lst[0+1]+lst[0+2]-lst[0+4])/5)
new_list.append((4*lst[1]+3*lst[1+1]+2*lst[1+2]+lst[1+3])/10)
for i in range(2, len(lst)-2):
   new_list.append((4*lst[i]+3*lst[i-1]+2*lst[i-2]+lst[i-3])/10)
new_list.append((4*lst[-2]+3*lst[-2-1]+2*lst[-2-2]+lst[-2-4])/10)
new_list.append((3*lst[-1]+2*lst[-1-1]+lst[-1-2]-lst[-1-4])/5)
print(new_list)
```

По крайней мере, он сделает то, что пытаетесь сделать Вы. Не уверен, что это то, что нужно для решения задачи.

Comment: С этим я разобрался, спасибо. Но у меня для первого элемента одна формула, для второго вторая, для всех элементов от 3 до предпоследнего включительно, ещё одна формула,  для предпоследнего и последнего тоже свои формулы, поэтому приходится писать 'range(lst[2], lst[-3])'

Comment: @BlameFlame 'Поэтому приходится писать заведомо неправильный код'?! Просто обработайте 0, 1, -2 и -1 элементы отдельно.

Comment: Да я понял, что он неправильный, спасибо. Но каким образом сделать правильно?

Comment: @BlameFlame дописал в ответе

Comment: Последнее дополнение. У меня выдает теперь ошибку "IndexError: list index out of range". Это из-за того, что мой входной массив это просто лист, с одной строкой получается?

Comment: @BlameFlame Да, конечно, везде замените `lst[i] --> lst[0][i]`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу - было бы очень удобно воспользоваться Pandas модулем

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [1]: lst = [90.0, 72.0, 68.5, 65.0, 62.0, 60.0, 59.0, 58.0]

In [2]: s = pd.Series(lst)

In [3]: s
Out[3]:
0    90.0
1    72.0
2    68.5
3    65.0
4    62.0
5    60.0
6    59.0
7    58.0
dtype: float64
```

Решение:

```
In [4]: result = s.rolling(5, center=True).mean()
   ...:
   ...: result.iloc[0] = np.dot(s.iloc[0:5], [3,2,1,0,-1])/5
   ...: result.iloc[1] = np.dot(s.iloc[1:5], [4,3,2,1])/10
   ...:
   ...: result.iloc[-2] = np.dot(s.iloc[-2:-5-2:-1], [4,3,2,0,1])/10
   ...: result.iloc[-1] = np.dot(s.iloc[-1:-5-1:-1], [3,2,1,0,-1])/5
   ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [5]: result
Out[5]:
0    84.10
1    68.55
2    71.50
3    65.50
4    62.90
5    60.80
6    60.85
7    57.40
dtype: float64

In [6]: result.sum()
Out[6]: 531.6
```

Если можно обойтись простым плавающим окном без хитрых формул для первых и последних двух элементов, то решение будет выглядеть гораздо проще:

```
In [7]: s.rolling(5, center=True).mean()
Out[7]:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    71.5
3    65.5
4    62.9
5    60.8
6     NaN
7     NaN
dtype: float64
```

или

```
In [8]: s.rolling(5, center=True, min_periods=1).mean()
Out[8]:
0    76.833333
1    73.875000
2    71.500000
3    65.500000
4    62.900000
5    60.800000
6    59.750000
7    59.000000
dtype: float64
```

чтобы прочитать Excel файл в Pandas.DataFrame:

```
fn = r'C:/Users/Blame/Desktop/graph.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(fn, header=None, usecols=[0,1], names=['col1','col2'])
```

если заменить `s` в решении выше на `df['col1']` или сделать присвоение: `s = df['col1']` то можно воспользоваться решением выше

Comment: Да, я смотрел про сглаживащие функции и сплайны, но задача такова, что мне самому надо написать программу для линейного сглаживания данных по пяти точкам. У меня только формулы есть для этого.

Comment: @BlameFlame, вы можете привести пример входного массива из 7 элементов и __выходной__ массив, чтобы было понятнее и чтобы можно было сверить ответ? Я не уверен что правильно понял ваши формулы из вопроса...